# set upper limit and lower limit in time for user before executing shutdown command in linux

Tags: linux, sudo, shutdown, sudoers

let's say
I want one of the non-root users named "Alex" to only allow to shutdown command but with the restriction like, he can only shutdown after minimum of 120 min and no delay more than 1000mins. Basically, to set upper limit and lower limit for executing the shutdown command.
To add on I am using Rocky Linux 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- download `shutdown` [C source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/shutdown/shutdown.c), modify it to check if the user is Alex, and if so, check the required time range. Then compile this source code to a program named like `my_shutdown`, install it to `/usr/local/bin`

  - and add it with `NOPASSWD` for alex in sudoers
  - or just for every other user exit your program, and set SUID bit on your executable.
  - or you can write the program from scratch instead of using existing shutdown.c implementation
- Or you can add specific list of combinations of arguments as `NOPASSWD` to sudoers, like `alex ALL=NOPASSWD: shutdown 120m` , `... 121m` `... 122m` etc. for every combination of arguments you want to support
- or you can write a wrapper that will parse the argument to shut down and check if it's in range, if it is, it will forward the call to `shutdown` executable. And add that wrapper into sudoers, or add SUID on it. Strongly consider not using a scripting language - for example, with python with any `import` and by manipulating PYTHONPATH environment variable, the user will be able to execute any code as root.

Comment: I added a file under sudoers.d and inside file I wrote a line like
`alex ALL=(ALL) /sbin/shutdown` This command runs perfectly and gives only sudo access to alex for shutdown but I am not able to set the minimum and maximum parameters which I need to set before shutting down

Comment: "Or you can add __specific list of combinations__ of arguments...". `but I am not able` What do you mean by "not able"? What have you tried? Have you tried listing the combinations of arguments you want to permit in the sudoers file?

Comment: if I keep is as `alex ALL=(ALL) /sbin/shutdown 120m` or even `alex ALL=(ALL) /sbin/shutdown 120`,
it throws error saying `Sorry, user alex is not allowed to execute '/sbin/shutdown' as root on rockyy9.`. so when I write anything at the end its not allowing to run the shutdown command also, sorry but I am new and not aware if there is any syntax mistake.

Comment: So add `NOPASSWD:`? See `man sudoers`, but I never understood the syntax.